# LINQ to iterate through IEnumerable and set duplicates to null

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable`

```
IEnumerable<Pets> pets;
```

It consists of

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Other { get; set; }
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

I want to iterate through this and find all prices that are duplicate and set those duplicate prices to null.

Say A cat and a Dog have same price: 10.55. I want to keep first one but remove all remaining prices.

Comment: What research have you done in trying to find a solution for this problem?  What attempted solutions have you tried, and what problems have you been having with those solutions?

Comment: I found a whole lot with list nothing that matches my need with IEnumerable. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: "remove" and "set price to null" are two different things - which is it?

Comment: it is set to null. I should have said set to null

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper a `decimal` cannot be `null` - you'd either need to  change it to `decimal?` or choose a "magic" value (would using 0 cause any problems?  How about -1?)  What effect does setting `Price` to `null` have overall?  (e.g. if you just "extracted" the first item with each price would that work better)?

Comment: You should improve this question with sample input and desired output, _set duplicates to null_ is still vague, you want to set the duplicate objects in the array / list as null? Or set the Price of duplicate objects as null? Or something else? Or the readers have to guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ways:

1) Remove duplicates (I recommend it):

```
var filtered = pets.GroupBy(pet => pet.Price).Select(group => group.First());
```

2) Sort & evalute - set null in place of duplicates as you wish (Are you sure that you want to set nulls instead of removing like in 1) ?).

```
var newPets = pets.OrderBy(per => pet.Price).ToList();
if (!newPets.Any()) return newPets;
var last = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < newPets.Count; i++) 
{
     if (newPets[i].Price == newPets[last].Price) newPets[i] = null;
     else last = i;
}

return newPets;
```

I think that ordering is sufficient in that case: `O(n * log n) + O(n)`  against  `O(n^2)` in custom iterates to search duplicates for each element.

3) Classic way (without sorting, slowest)

```
var newPets = pets.ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < newPets.Count; i++)
{
    if (newPets[i] == null) continue;
    var price = newPets[i].Price;
    for (var j = i + 1; j < newPets.Count; j++)
    {
        if (newPets[j].Price == price) newPets[j] = null;
    }
}
```

As **D Stanley** has noticed (but I've missed it) you may have to set `Price` to `null` instead of whole record. Then simply change it to `decimal?` and then write `newPets[i].Price = null;` instead of null`ing whole record.

Comment: as third variant use [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters a `decimal` can't be null, so I'll answer it as if you had a `decimal?` type so you understand the process.

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*. You *could* project a new collection based on the original, but a `foreach` may be more appropriate:

```
// list to keep tack of found prices
var prices = new List<decimal>();
foreach(Pet pet in pets)
{
    if(prices.Contains(pet.Price.Value))
        // price was found - set this one to null
        pet.Price = null;
    else
        // add to the list of "found" prices
        prices.Add(pet.Price.Value);
}
```

Comment: methinks better `HashSet<decimal>` that simply List :-)

Comment: @Grundy for performance?  Sure. I was more interested in illustrating the process than giving optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the Price is now nullable (`decimal?`)

```
return pets
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Price)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(x => (new[] { x.First() }).Union(x.Skip(1).Select(n => new Pet { Name = n.Name, Other = n.Other, Price = null })))
    .ToList();
```